# React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

Consider this example:

```
 let memoizedCb = React.useCallback(
    memoize((param) => () => someFunction(param)),
    []
  );
```

where `memoize` is from external library like "fast-memoize". Above code gives warning:

> React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are
> unknown. Pass an inline function instead

I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19240) thread which if we adapt to my use case would suggest this as solution (*if I am not wrong*):

```
const memoizedCb = React.useMemo(
  () => memoize((param) => () => someFunction(param)),
  []
);
```

What is the warning about? **why** does `useMemo` fix this problem?

NOTE: `someFunction` is defined outside the function component so it is not needed as a dependency.

Comment: It's a linter warning, not an actual error. You can either ignore it, or use a pattern that doesn't trigger it (like the `useMemo` one you got from that github thread).

Comment: @JaredSmith I see it is a linter warning I am trying to explain why there is no warning with `useMemo` though

Comment: Ask the people that wrote the eslint plugin. You are correct that the two are logically equivalent. Maybe the have the same rule, after all you are passing an inline function to `useMemo`.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah thats why I got confused because the two seemed the same :)

Comment: useCallback already memoizes the function, so using another utility to memoize the inline function is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: @Derek Nope this way you are achieving different functionality.

Comment: You're better off defining your memoized function outside the component itself then, especially if they have no dependencies on props or derived values created inside the component.

Comment: @Derek yeah but the question is not about that.

Comment: `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` ESlint rule should be burned to ashes and spread over the ocean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems the warning is there because `useCallback` (and also `useMemo` see below) expect inline function as argument (don't know why though).

So in the solution from the question:

```
const memoizedCb = React.useMemo(
  () => memoize((param) => () => someFunction(param)),
  []
);
```

they used `useMemo` to *imitate* `useCallback` functionality while also passing an *inline* function to `useMemo` as the warning required:

> React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are
> unknown. **Pass an inline function instead**

---

That warning is not specific to `useCallback`, you get same warning if you just replace `useCallback` with `useMemo` in the first example:

```
 // For testing
 // Gives same warning
 let memoizedCb = React.useMemo(
    memoize((param) => () => someFunction(param)),
    []
 );
```

Answer (score 9):

As a more general explanation the below will produce a warning:

```
const someFuncWrap = (fn) => (e) => fn(e)
const memoizedFunc = useCallback(someFuncWrap(foo), [someFuncWrap, foo]);
```

Changing the `useCallback` to a `useMemo` with an inline function passes.

```
const someFuncWrap = (fn) => (e) => fn(e)
const memoizedFunc = useMemo(() => someFuncWrap(foo), [someFuncWrap, foo]);
```

This is because to parse the hook eslint needs to see it in the following form:

```
useMemo(() => foo, [foo]);
useCallback((bar) => foo(bar), [foo]);
```

Comment: Am I right to think that: useMemo evaluates the expression before caching it between renders, while useCallback caches the expression itself as the function to execute?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the useCallback expects an inline function. If you pass a returned function from another function, eslint won't be able to figure out what are the dependancies of the function, so it will show this warning.

Here I think, eslint is failing to determine the dependancies of `somefunction` and thus it cannot evaluate the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule because to evaluate this rule eslint should be able to identify is there any dependancy like state, props for the function passed to useCallback hook. So eslint is asking you to pass an inline function which it will understand and can evalute for lint rules.

Comment: it's not complaining about `someFunction` rather `memoize`. I was more interested why there is no warning in the second case

Comment: This eslint rule should be burned to ashes and spread over the ocean.